How to open "SAP Crystal Reports" file in the InTouch HMI application?
We are analysing "SAP Crystal Reports" for our existing reporting requirements.
Currently we use Crystal Reports 8.5 that can be embedded as ActiveX control within the InTouch HMI application to generate and export the requested report at run-time to PDF, in multiple languages, including Chinese.
However as a number of Crystal Reports SDKs have been retired by Crystal Reports 2008 (12.x) and as OCX is not supported now, the newer versions of the product no longer provide a control that can be embedded or included in the InTouch HMI application.
Questions:

Can latest "SAP Crystal Reports" be embedded in same way as Crystal Reports 8.5 within the InTouch HMI application and generate and export report at run-time to PDF?

Can "SAP Crystal Reports" file be opened and exported to PDF from .NET code?



The report created using the SAP Crystal Reports can be viewed from InTouch HMI app using the following steps:

Create report using the SAP Crystal Report software.

Import the “CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer class” into the ArchestrA graphics, of the InTouch HMI application,

Add CrystalReportViewer control to the application symbol and assign the ReportSource property of that control to the report file created in step 1.


